# Cannot create intent with certain trigger phrases

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, google-assistant-sdk, google-assist-api

It seems Google Assistant is unable to handle certain trigger phrases in the intent. The ones I have come across are the following:

- Send message to scott
- chat with q
- Send text to felix

It seems to work fine inside dialogflow simulator. However, it doesn't work at all in Action Console Simulator or on a real device like google home mini. On Action Console Simulator, it gives "You cannot use standard Google Assistant features in the Simulator. If you want to try them, use Google Assistant on your phone or other compatible devices" and on a real device it gives an error "I am sorry, i cannot help you .." and exits completely and leaves the device in a funky state. It doesn't seem to trigger any fallback intent. I have tried adding input context but make no difference.

It's very easy to reproduce. Just create a demo action with an intent for the above phrases along with "communicate with penny", invoke your app and then try the above phrases after the welcome message. It will only work if you say "communicate with ..".

Is this a known issue/limitation? Is there a list of phrases that we cannot use to trigger an intent?

Answer (score 0):

The Actions on Google libraries ([Node.js](https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/nodejsv2/overview), [Java](https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/java/overview)) include a limited feature-set that allow third-party developers to build actions for the Google Assistant.

Standard features available in the Google Assistant (like "text Mary 'Hello, world!'") won't be available in your action until you build that feature, using fulfillment.

Rather than looking for a list of phrases you *can't* use, review [the documentation for invocation](https://developers.google.com/actions/discovery/explicit) to see what you *can* use. Third party actions for the Google Assistant are invoked like:

[image: Explicit Invocation for the Google Assistant]

To learn how to get started building for the Google Assistant, check out Google's codelabs at https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/actions-1/#0

If you've already reviewed Google's Actions on Google Codelabs through level three, consider updating your question to include a list of your intents and a code sample of your fulfillment, so other Stack Overflow users can understand how your project behaves.

See also, [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)